# Layout for Gmail on Honeycomb

Tags: android

Is that possible to have a look on the layout for the `Compose message` screen of Gmail app under Honeycomb?

Comment: Which parts are you interested in?

Comment: What is a value for the padding from left and right.

Comment: In apps written for the Holo theme padding and margins are almost always an integer multiple of 16dp. When a situation calls for something smaller, 8dp and 4dp are often used.

Comment: The padding appears to be 240dp on left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around a bit, it seems the Gmail app is not open source. So I'm assuming finding the source code may be very difficult if not impossible. If I find anything I will update this post though.